# Thunderbird mailing

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird on MS allows the suppression of the e-mails of recipients. On Ubuntu 14.0 this option does not seem to appear. Is it concealed, or can I add it in some way? I send out multiple mailing in which some recipients wish to keep their e-addresses private.

---

Thanks for that I usually use that facility, but for some reason it does not appear on the ubuntu version. That is what puzzles me!

Incidentally, the appearance on my screen is quite different. I reloaded Ubuntu recently after having removed it a couple of years ago. Th appearance is the same as in the past - despite what should have been a full update - could the problem lie there?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Bcc` - this stands for blind carbon copy - instead of `To` or `cc` in the email header.

[image]